# File upload script doesn't work when moved into a different function

Tags: php, file-upload

I have some PHP file upload function that worked perfectly well. For some reason I trigger the upload function from a different spot of my site. That is a different function from the one I used to trigger it from. HTML works just fine but:

```
$_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']
```

returns "null".

What could possibly be wrong?

here's the code:

```
if (isset($_POST['upload'])) {

    $target_path = "uploads/";

    $target_path = $target_path.basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'],$target_path)) echo "ok";
    else echo "problem";
}

else {
    echo '<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000" />';
    echo 'Choose a file to upload: <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" /><br />';
    echo '<input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload File" />';
    echo '</form>'';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what was wrong. It was a childish mistake actually. By moving the upload script into a new function I accidentally included the "multipart/form-data" form into a simple form. That caused the submit buttons to be "confused" and leaving the $_FILES variable null.

I'd like to thank the people that posted on this topic!
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it be

```
$_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']
```

Note the upper-case variable.

Comment: it actually is! I just didn't press the shift button when I posted :)

Comment: @Mob: please no, don't use quotes for variables

Comment: @Mob I tried echo $_FILES but that didn't get me any outcome. i'll try var_dump and let you know.

Comment: @gianniskpf Ok. Do this `var_dump($_FILES);`

Answer (score 0):

When you're not sure, just use

```
var_dump($var);
```

in this case,

```
var_dump($_FILES['uploadedfile']);
```

or even better

```
var_dump($_FILES);
```

Comment: if var_dump($FILES) still returns null? what could be the problem then? does the triggering point matter at all?

Comment: @gianniskpf: you do not have any file input field or you have got wrong encryption set on your form

Comment: That's the funny thing! It worked absolutely fine before! And I didn't mess with it at all!

Comment: @gianniskpf: please post a form you're trying to send here

Comment: ok i did. i'm confident though that the form itself isn't the issue! thanks btw for you help ;)